# How to improve Postgres query with pg_trgm?

Tags: postgresql

### Problem

I have Postgres database where is more than 100 m rows. I need to find the most similar text in all DB.

To find text similarity I use pg_trgm to filter most similar and then after fetched results with Python and RapidFuzz I compare texts more closely.

What I found is that I can set pg_trgm threshold. So I do that. Also i created an index on the column where I do comparison

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON goods_goods USING GIN (name gin_trgm_ops)
```

There I found two types of indexes, GIN and GIST and after reading some explanations GIST would suggest for this type of work, but after real checking, GIN working better(faster)  GIST - 9min GIN - 12sec

---

I need to compare many columns so there also is some problems.

I can do that with pg_trgm `similarity(concat_ws(' ', col1, col2, col3), 'some text')`, and it's working fine while there is small amount of rows.

Because after setting threshold on similarity I need to use it in WHERE clause. And what's happening execution time is 12min. There I also find some explanation. `We can't index function concat_ws`
But there is also operator || which one we can index and execution time is also faster 12 sec.

```
WHERE name % 'Some text `'
```

But `||` operator didn't remove Null values. And if one of the column is Null, so the all value is Null, and threshold is not correct.

### IDEA

Then my idea was to not concatenate string in where clause but just use only one most important column and then after that with RapidFuzz do more comparison with concatenation

In some times, it would be better to do queries with decreasing threshold. Start with threshold 0.9 if there are no results as I want, then decrease to 0.8 and so on. While threshold is 0.3 or fetched some count of results.

This idea helps save some time. Because to filter values with threshold 0.9 is just a sec. If there are no results returned. And then 0.8 also just a sec if no results or just 3 results.
But if set threshold in general on minimum and then fetch and compare all these results in some cases then would be more than 50k results and time about 120sek. And better would be if we checked some higher threshold. 1sek + 1sek + 5sek(here we found wanted count of results). so there is only 7sek with decreasing threshold.

#### Here is my queries and indexes:

> all DB have 110m rows and source 37 in example have 45m rows

1:

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON goods_goods USING GIN (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

2:

```
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.3;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT id, article, brand, vendor_code, name
FROM goods_goods
WHERE name % 'Some text with some numbers 34/44 and chars :}{:">?>"??' AND source_id = 37
```

3:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on goods_goods  (cost=2242.04..40605.89 rows=4026 width=165) (actual time=12704.821..12704.822 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: ((name)::text % 'Some text with some numbers 34/44 and chars :}{:"">?>""??'::text)"
"  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 330475"
"  Filter: (source_id = 37)"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=36338 lossy=48099"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..2241.03 rows=9737 width=0) (actual time=5923.925..5923.926 rows=91004 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: ((name)::text % 'Some text with some numbers 34/44 and chars :}{:"">?>""??'::text)"
"Planning Time: 3.028 ms"
"Execution Time: 12705.348 ms"
```

### Question

1. - In WHERE i need to filter another column, and it's also needed to be indexed?
     like `WHERE name % 'Some text' AND some_id = 123`

And if there is five AND? I need to index all of them by one?

create index on some_id1

create index on some_id2

create index on some_id3

2. - If one query takes time about 10sec can I split it by multiprocesses? Like if I have 32 queries and each query takes 10sec so with 32 processes I can get 32 results in 10sec?
3. - Is there an option in Postgres to give some array with queries and return would be also an array with results?
4. - How can I improve this or do it faster? Because in real work there are thousands of queries and if one process would do that this would take some months. So I want to do i faster but don't know how. Maybe there are some ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're largely having trouble with (a) *optimising the query and indices* and (b) *how to get the data for a large number of queries in some realistic time*. I'll try to answer them both one by one.

1. **Optimising the query and indices (comparing multiple columns)**

   I think you've got two doubts here again:

   - Supporting queries with concatenated string avoiding `null`'s.

     Well it can be handled by making use of `coalesce`. So your query should look like:

     `similarity(coalesce(col1, '') || ' ' || coalesce(col2, '') || ' ' || coalesce(col3, '')), 'some text')`

     And the corresponding index to support this query would be:

     `CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON goods_goods USING GIN ((coalesce(col1, '') || ' ' || coalesce(col2, '') || ' ' || coalesce(col3, ''))) gin_trgm_ops)`
   - Supporting queries with columns of different type (`WHERE name % 'Some text' AND some_id = 123`)

     You can create an index like this to support index search:

     `CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON goods_goods USING GIN (name gin_trgm_ops, some_id);`

   If you wish to combine above two, then the corresponding index would be:

   `CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON goods_goods USING GIN ((coalesce(col1, '') || ' ' || coalesce(col2, '') || ' ' || coalesce(col3, ''))) gin_trgm_ops, some_id)`
2. **How to get the data for a large number of queries in some realistic time (I'll try to answer the queries posed by you in 2, 3 & 4)**

   Above solutions on optimising the query and indices will surely improve your query performance. But, if you wish to improve further you could look at establishing multiple connections with your database and firing queries in parallel. This would give you a certain performance gain. You could achieve this by looking at popular ORMs out there. Further, you could have multiple read replicas of your master Postgres machine so that you have more compute power and even more connections. Still you can look at partitioning your data and run your queries on individual partitions instead of a single large table and come up with a solution to merge/recompute the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot about index creation. So there is a unnecessary bracket before word `gin_trgm_ops`. I can't edit because I need to edit at least 6 characters. But with this indexing I decreas time 4x times. I just indexed all columns by one but now all together